# TextView loses Alpha information after visibility is changed (when animateLayoutChange is true)

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, material-design

When `android:animateLayoutChanges` for my layout is enabled and I change the group visibility to `GONE` and back it to `VISIBLE` the TextView's alpha is reseted to `1`.

```
<TextView

    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alpha="0.2"
    android:padding="16dp"


    android:text="TextView"

    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Group
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:constraint_referenced_ids="textView"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)


        button.setOnClickListener {
            println(group.visibility)
            group.visibility = if (group.visibility == View.VISIBLE) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE

        }

    }
}
```

ps. I also make a try setting the TextView visibility directly and same problem happening:

```
textView.visibility = if (textView.visibility == View.VISIBLE) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: Yes, its because animate layout changes basically uses alpha property to animate.

Comment: but why it doesn't back the alpha to the previous value?

Comment: It just doesn't. Go ahead and report a bug. Though you can work around it: configure the `layoutTransition` of the parent ViewGroup of the thing you want to animate to use your own animator for transitionType `APPEARING`, with the right target alpha you want.